# How to retrieve parameters into initialization controller of the application

Tags: angularjs, parameters, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS application using ui-router module.
I want to manage language in the URLs of the application like this :

- site.com/en --> home page in english
- site.com/en/login --> login page in english
- site.com/de --> home page in german
- site.com/de/login --> login page in german
- ....

My goal is to retrieve this language used in URL in the main controller of the application in order to :
- check if this language is available for the application,
- request some WS to initialize the application.

I have created the following app.routes.ts file to manage routes :

**app.routes.ts :**

```
'use strict';
myApp.config(function($locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider,
                              $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider,
                              $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('notFound', {
        url: '/notFound',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/notFound/notFoundView.html',
                controller: 'NotFoundController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root', {
        url: '/:languageCode',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'app/header/headerView.html',
                controller: 'HeaderController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'app/footer/footerView.html',
                controller: 'FooterController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.home', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/home/homeView.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/login/loginView.html',
                controller: 'LoginController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/en');

//html5 removes the need for # in URL
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true
});

});
```

I have defined the controller of the index.html :

**part of index.html :**

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="InitializationController">
```

And I want to retrieve the language (the 'languageCode' used in the parameters) in the InitializationController :

**initializationController.ts :**

```
'use strict';
/**
 * InitializationController is used as controller of the index page
 * Used to initialize the main parameters of the application
 */
class InitializationController {

static $inject = ['$stateParams', 'ParametersService', 'LayoutService'];

constructor(private $stateParams: any,
            private parametersService:ParametersService,
            private layoutService: LayoutService) {
    // Retrieve the language used in the url
    console.log('test:' + this.$stateParams);
    // Retrieve the main parameters of the application from configuration files
    parametersService.initialize()
        .then(this.initApplication.bind(this));
}

/**
 * Initialize the web application
 */
private initApplication(): void {
    // Retrieve the language used in the url
    console.log('test:' + this.$stateParams);
    // Retrieve the language to use to display labels
    var language: string = ""; //TODO
    // Retrieve the data used in all pages : header, footer and menu   
    this.layoutService.retrieveLayoutByLanguage(language);
}

}

myApp.controller('InitializationController', InitializationController);
```

The routes defined in app.routes.ts seems to be OK.

Is it possible to retrieve my languageCode parameter in this controller ?

In debug mod, I see that $stateParams is empty : there is no languageCode parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem :

In the initializationController.ts, I have added a listener on $stateChangeStart, an then I am now able to retrieve my language parameter :

**initializationController.ts :**

```
'use strict';
/**
 * InitializationController is used as controller of the index page
 * Used to initialize the main parameters of the application
 */
class InitializationController {

    static $inject = ['$stateParams', 'ParametersService', 'LayoutService'];

    constructor(private $stateParams: any,
        private parametersService:ParametersService,
        private layoutService: LayoutService) {
        // Retrieve the parameters
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', this.retrieveParameters.bind(this));
        // Retrieve the main parameters of the application from configuration files
        parametersService.initialize()
        .then(this.initApplication.bind(this));
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the web application
     */
    private initApplication(): void {
        // Retrieve the language to use to display labels
        var language: string = ""; //TODO
        // Retrieve the data used in all pages : header, footer and menu   
        this.layoutService.retrieveLayoutByLanguage(language);
    }

    private retrieveParameters(event: any,
                           toState: angular.ui.IState,
                           toParams: any,
                           fromState: angular.ui.IState,
                           fromParams: any): void {
        this.languageInUrl = toParams.languageCode;
    }

}

myApp.controller('InitializationController', InitializationController);
```